# anaconda can't install in jupyter notebook conda packages

Tags: anaconda, conda

everything was Ok with jupyter notebook, but then I tried to install by:
`!conda install --yes --prefix {syz.prefix} psycopg2-binary` and I got this error in jupyter `EnvironmentLocationNotFound: Not a conda environment: C:\Users\Anonymous\{sys.prefix}`

Comment: In addition to Peter's excellent advice, keep in mind going forward anything you see suggesting using an exclamation point in conjunction with `conda install` is likely outdated and should be suspect. A few years ago, the magic command `%conda install` was added to insure installation to the environment backing the notebook kernel. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) about the modern `%conda install` command.

Answer (score 2):

You can't mix virtualenv or venv with conda environements.
Learn conda basics here: [Managing conda environments](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)